# Facebook profile link stored in MySQL doesn't work when returned to HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, facebook

I have stored the following code in a MySQL text field:

```
'<img class="marginRight roundPicture" src="'+pictureUrl+'"/><a href="'+link+'" target="_blank" />'+name+'</a>'
```

using an Ajax $.post in jQuery. `pictureUrl`, `link` and `name` are variables from JavaScript. I store the code successfully in my MySQL database.

When I return the code from MySQL using Ajax and update a table with it, the `pictureUrl` link works, but the `link` in the `<a>` tag doesn't. The links look like this:

`pictureUrl`  =  `https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xat1/v/t1.0...`

`link` = `https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/163665554...`

I put `...` at the end because they are too long to display here.

If I copy the link from the code and access it manually in the browser it works, but for some reasons it doesn't work when updating the code automatically in the page.

Comment: It looks like a problem with a JavaScript code. Could You show some?

Comment: i am using this script to update the table.[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript

Comment: I am using Bootstrap table., but I don't think this is a problem though..,

Answer (score 0):

It is a string when it comes from the database. In order to display it correctly, you need to convert it to HTML format using [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).